# How could I separate this string by 2 character increments?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, delimiter

There are no delimiters and the string itself comes from a file formatted like the following:

BB

GB

GB

BG

GG

GB

GB

GB

GB

GG

After using the following code I'm left with BBGBGBBGGGGBGBGBGBGG, as printed from the print statement after `token = in.nextLine( )`; My goal for this program is to assign every 2 characters to their variables and increment them to get a count. I just don`t know how to increment and assign them correctly. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Family
{
   public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
    //variables defined
    int numGB = 0;
    int numBG = 0;
    int numGG = 0;
    int numBB = 0;
    int totalNum = 0;
    double probBG;
    double probGG;
    double probBB;
    String token ="";
    int spaceDeleter = 0;
    int token2Sub = 0;
    
    File fileName = new File ("test1.txt"); 
    
    Scanner in = new Scanner(fileName); //scans file
    
    System.out.println("Composition statistics for families with two children");
    while(in.hasNextLine())
    {
        token = in.nextLine( ); //recives token from scanner
        System.out.print(token);
        if(token.equals("GB"))
        {
        numGB = numGB + 1;
        }
        else if(token.equals("BG"))
        {
        numBG = numBG + 1;
        }
        else if(token.equals("GG"))
        {
        numGG = numGG + 1;
        }
        else if(token.equals("BB"))
        {
        numBB = numBB + 1;
        }
        else if(token.equals(""))
        {
        spaceDeleter =+ 1; //tried to delete space to no avial
        }
        else 
        {
        System.out.println("Data reading error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "assign every 2 characters **to their variables**"?

Comment: You might want to look at `String.substring()`

Comment: @Spectric for example numBG needs to be incremented by 1 for every occurrence of "BG"  in the string

Comment: @RIVERMAN2010 Thank you, I used token = token.substring(0); after every loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a map.  To split the string, replace every two characters with the string following by some unused character or characters.  Then split on those characters.  The rest is to just stream the array of character pairs and do a frequency count.

```
String s = "BBGBGBBGGGGBGBGBGBGG";
Map<String, Long> count =
        Arrays.stream(s.replaceAll("..", "$0#").split("#"))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a,
                        Collectors.counting()));

count.forEach((k,v)-> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

Prints

```
GG -> 2
BB -> 1
BG -> 1
GB -> 6
```